# Cannot enter the condition in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

My problem is that I cannot enter to the condition even if it meets the value of my two variables and I don't know why. It seems like there's something wrong with my code here:

```
$.post("sendemail.php",
{
    email: myemail
},
function(data,status){

alert(data); // the output of this is notemail.

if (data == "notexist")
{
    alert("not exist");
}
else if (data == "notemail")   // expected condition to enter     
{
    alert("not email");
}
else if (data == "success")
{
    alert("success!");
}
else                        // but it enter's in this condition
{
    alert("error");
}
});
```

As you can see in this code the value of `data` would be `notemail` so it should go to this condition `else if (data == "notemail")` but why is it entering to this condition `else` which alert's error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `if (data.trim() == "notexist")`

Comment: If the condition is not fulfilled it means the values are not equal. Since we cannot run the code, it's up to you to inspect `data` and figure out its real value. `alert` is not a debugging tool. Set a breakpoint and inspect the variable.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Pranav it really worked. I wonder why, can you please explain? It if my first time to encounter this type of error. Many thanks...

Comment: @Felix Kling, I've made sure that the values are equal that there are no something(like white spaces) in my code but I don't know why it worked after I applied what Pranav said.

Comment: Well, apparently `data` contained leading or trailing white spaces. So whatever you do to ensure that it doesn't, doesn't work.